# How to have an even light source?

Tags: lighting, loop

I am trying to make a looped animation. I initially made a plane, duplicated it 3 times and laid it across. I rigged the camera to only roll within the confines of the first plane. It appears seamless in Material Preview but in Rendered View, the "back to start" is noticeable because the light source is behind the camera, the loop does not look seamless. The plane closest to the camera is lighter than the plane further away (obviously) so whenever the camera is close to the end of the animation, the plane is a bit darker and when it goes back to the first frame, it becomes light all of a sudden. My question I guess is how do I make the second plane to be as lit as the first plane?

Comment: a screenshot would help a lot...a blend file even more...

Comment: Sure! I will send it to you.

Comment: Make your light a Sun light

Comment: I did make it a sun light but I positioned it behind the camera at a low angle instead of it being above the scene. Here is the link. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DM9D2Qkw60QOAxuDcFPGcXmtMLUJZkIK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If you want the planes to be "unshaded" (unaffected by scene light), connect the image texture (or color) directly to the Material Output without any shader (BSDF) in between.

Comment: Wouldn't that make the plane not lit? The trees are attached to the plane like hair by the way.

Comment: unfortunately you didn't pack your resources before uploading. So i cannot really see your scene. Would be helpful if you do File->external data -> pack resources, then save your file and upload that again.

Comment: i think Christopher's proposal is good. Can you explain us why the sunlight didn't help you? If you use point lights one way might be to parent them to your camera so they "walk" with the camera and so the light should be the same when leaving and entering the scene. But of course this changes the look in between of your scene (what of course does the sunlight as well). Or you insert the same point light(s) which affect your scene at the start at the end in the same position relative to your cam.

Comment: I think it what Chris said would probably fix it, I just don't know how to execute it. I am currently uploading the file. I'm sorry I was confused your are both named Chris. I thought I was talking to the same person.

Comment: Here it is. I have packed the other files and saved it. I hope it appears on there. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_GdAQO7l2xraavFQDxqQ7WQVMRAS1TUR/view?usp=sharing